# implementing negation by overriding __neg__ in python

Tags: python, class

I am learning classes right now and I attempted to make a program which operates on Fractions.
I am posting some extract from the code:

```
class Fraction():
    def __init__(self,numerator,denominator=1):
        g = gcd(numerator,denominator)
        self.numerator = numerator / g
        self.denominator = denominator / g

    def __add__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other,int):
            other = Fraction(other)
        return Fraction((self.numerator * other.denominator + self.denominator * other.numerator),(self.denominator * other.denominator))

    def __neg__(self):
        return (-self.numerator , self.denominator)

    def __sub__(self,other):
        other = other.__neg__()
        return self + (-other)

    def __mul__(self , other):
        if isinstance(other,int):
            other = Fraction(other)
        return Fraction(self.numerator*other.numerator,self.denominator*other.denominator)

    __rmul__ = __mul__

    def printit(self):
        print '(' + str(self.numerator) + '/' + str(self.denominator) + ')'

def gcd(m,n):
    if(m%n == 0):
        return n
    else:
        return gcd(n,m%n)

#Input is of the form

    Fraction.printit(Fraction(5,6) + Fraction(1,6))
    Fraction.printit(Fraction(5,6) - Fraction(1,6))
```

Previous Indentation error has been taken care of. It was a sort of malfunctioning when I copied my code from this page to notepad++. Indenting again solved the problem.
Now the error which is arising is this:

```
(1/1)     #This is the first answer, works perfectly. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Fractions.py", line 36, in <module>
    Fraction.printit(Fraction(5,6) - Fraction(1,6))
File "Fractions.py", line 15, in __sub__
    return (self + (-other))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple'
```

Comment: Where is your `__init__` method?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. For most languages, this is just for readability, but bad indentation will break Python code. If your indentation is good in the question, it makes it easier for people to run, test, and reproduce errors in your code. That makes it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with this code, but the immediate problem causing that error message is that your `__neg__` and `__sub__` functions need to *call* the `__neg__` function (`self.__neg__()`, not `self.__neg__`).

Here's a version of your code that works (to the extent that it parses and doesn't throw exceptions):

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Fraction(namedtuple('Fraction', ('numerator', 'denominator'))):

    def __add__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            other = Fraction(other)
        return Fraction(
            (self.numerator * other.denominator +
             self.denominator * other.numerator),
            (self.denominator * other.denominator))

    def __neg__(self):
        return Fraction(-self.numerator, self.denominator)

    def __sub__(self,other):
        other = other.__neg__()
        return self.__add__(other)

    def printit(self):
        print '(' + str(self.numerator) + '/' + str(self.denominator) + ')'

(Fraction(5,6) + Fraction(1,6)).printit()
(Fraction(5,6) - Fraction(1,6)).printit()
```

Comment: ,This is the error I got
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "Fractions2.py", line 37, in <module>`
   ` Fraction.printit(Fraction(5,6) + Fraction(1,6))`
  `File "Fractions2.py", line 6, in __init__`
 `   self.numerator = numerator / g`
`AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Comment: You can't mutate the attributes in my implementation because they belong to `namedtuple`, which is literally a Python `tuple` (so it's immutable). It's generally unwise to mutate attributes. I suggest writing a different function to do normalization rather than doing it in the constructor. Code tends to be a lot easier to understand when a constructor's sole responsibility is to store the attributes that it is given.

Answer (score 2):

You assigning the name `self` to the method `self.__neg__` in the line:

```
self = self.__neg__
```

Then, you're assigning the name `other` to the method `other.__neg__` in the line:

```
other = other.__neg__
```

So, when you call, `self.__add__(other)`, you are trying to add *a method* to a fraction.

Instead, use...

```
def __neg__(self):
    return Fraction(-self.numerator, self.denominator)

def __sub__(self, other):
    return self + -other
```

Comment: You need to `return` the result of calling `__add__`. You could also just do `return self + -other`, rather than calling `__add__` explicitly.

Comment: @Blckknght Updated as such

Comment: @ Jared Goguen,
After making the above changes, this error is raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
' File "Fractions.py", line 37, in <module>
  Fraction.printit(Fraction(5,6) - Fraction(1,6))
 File "Fractions.py", line 17, in __sub__
  self + (-other)                                           
 TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple'  '

Comment: @hiteshn97 It would help if you posted your full class, with proper indentation. This code works fine for me, so the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: @JaredGoguen I have posted my entire code and also the `error` which comes.

Comment: @JaredGoguen the code has worked! although self + (- other) was causing problem,
I replace it with ' self.__add__(other) '
This worked

Answer (score 0):

Running this should help elucidate as well:

```
def __neg__(self):
    print('self is a ' + str(type(self)))
    print('self.__neg__ is a ' + str(type(self.__neg__)))
    self = self.__neg__
    print('self is now a ' + str(type(self)))
    return self
```

Comment: I didn't know type() can tell about instancemethods as well. Thanks, but some errors are still coming replacing my code with this.
`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'denominator' `
Posting full error gets messy, but in the end it went to line 8, __add__ function before giving up.
I have added my complete code above.